# Migrating Visual Studio User Options File (.user file)

Tags: visual-studio, settings

When I give a copy of a solution to a student, the .user file is regenerated with default settings (because he is a different user).

This is inconvenient as each new developer has to manually enter in a number of properties (e.g "Debug command", "debug working directory" and "debug command arguments" ).

Is their anyway to, either:

1. save these debug settings in the .vcproj file
2. "import" the old .user file into the new .user file

I know I can just rename the old .user file, but is there a "correct" way of preserving these settings?

Answer (score 3):

I stumped upon [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vcgeneral/thread/6fe5f935-ec7c-4c10-89c0-b02961a3b6df), it seems one can change *.vcproj.DOMAIN.USER.user to *.vcproj.user and the settings are preloaded to whoever gets the user file.
The only downside is that if both files exist *.vcproj.DOMAIN.USER.user will take precedence, so if you add *.vcproj.user to your source control you should ask colleagues to delete their own user files which is a shame.
I am using vsprops to define user macros for many 3rd party library locations, and use them to build my project, it is a shame I cannot pass save debugging environment in a portable way.

Answer (score 0):

As its name says it all it's a user file... so specific to every user.

Comment: I don't see why the "Debug command", "Debug working directory" and "Debug command arguments" properties would be specific to every user. Surely, most of the time, all developers on a project would like to run the same debug command line

Answer (score 0):

There are project properties StartAction and StartArguments. Never edited them directly in a vcproj, but it is possible. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984540(v=vs.71).aspx